# Silex ExecutionContext::getValidator() not found when handleRequest or bind called

Tags: forms, validation, silex

I have the following silex code to present a simple form and message upon completion:

```
$app->register(new Silex\Provider\FormServiceProvider\FormServiceProvider());
$app->register(new Silex\Provider\ValidatorServiceProvider());

$app->match('/contact', function(Request $request) use ($app) {

$form = $app['form.factory']->createBuilder('form', null)
    ->add('name', 'text', array('required' => true, 'label' => 'Name',))
    ->add('submit', 'submit')
    ->getForm();

$form->handleRequest($request);

if ($form->isValid()) {

    die('success);
}

    return $app['twig']->render('contact.html.twig', array(
        'form'   => $form->createView(),
));
```

However on form submit I get presented with an error:

```
Call to undefined method Symfony\\Component\\Validator\\ExecutionContext::getValidator() 
in /home/user/project/vendor/symfony/form/Symfony
/Component/Form/Extension/Validator/Constraints/FormValidator.php on line 56
```

I am registering the ValidatorServiceProvider as above, so I am stumped to what it could be.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks to be a Symfony bug.  Backporting [this commit](https://github.com/symfony/Form/commit/fb0765dd0317c75d1c023a654dc6d805e0d95b0d) fixed it for me.

Comment: I dropped my version of `symfony\forms` down one and it fixed the issue, thank you

Comment: Thanks a lot for posting this! Helped my problem as well.

Comment: Similarly - I had included the symfony/validator component to my composer.json even though I was using the symfony/frameworks-standard-edition package.  I removed it and form validation is now working.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

to fix it update you composer.json to specify symfony 2.5.**2** :

```
"symfony/symfony": "2.5.2",
```

instead of

```
"symfony/symfony": "~2.5",
```

Then move composer.lock to composer.lock.bak and run

```
composer update symfony/symfony
```

That solved the problem for me.

Or you can wait for symfony 2.5.4 that should solve this problem :

https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/11580

Comment: Don't remove the lock file as this will update everything and loose the versions the project was locked to. instead, do `composer update symfony/symfony` to update that package only, with no need to change the lock file

Answer (score 0):

You should register the Validator before the FormServiceProvider.